# React-native componentWillUnmount not being called

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I'm running on Android and if I used the hardware back button to exit the application the componentWillUnmount function gets called.  However, if I use the square button to show the list of running apps and swipe to close the function does not get called.

Any ideas on how to detect when the app is being closed so that I can clear timers, save data etc.

Thanks.

Comment: I have run into the same problem. Have you got any solution to this issue?

Comment: For me it is not even triggered when app is in background (back button pressed)

Answer (score 3):

You can check AppState Api for information about detecting current state foreground or active. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appstate.html

Comment: Thanks for the info, but it is not related to my question.

Comment: @Railton i don't know why componentWillUnmount isn't being called, but this answer is related to your question because you could listen to AppState event of 'background' and do the cleanup code there in the handler

Comment: I want the app to keep running in background so I can't do code cleanup when switching to background.

Comment: Exactly what I need. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem.  To solve it, I didn't attach an event listener to the stateChange.  Instead I just look at AppState.currentState inside of the componentDidMount() function.

The problem was that eventListeners were getting *attached* when the component mounted, but not becoming detached at componentWillUnmount.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using react-navigation 4.x you can use the code below (Copied from somewhere else).
I think this issue will be solved in react-navigation 5.x.

```
componentDidMount() {
  const {navigation} = this.props;
  this.focusListener = navigation.addListener('didFocus', () => {
  const focused = navigation.isFocused();
    if (focused) {
      console.log('mount');
    }
  });
  this.blurListener = navigation.addListener('willBlur', () => {
    console.log('unmount');
  });
}
componentWillUnmount() {
  this.focusListener.remove();
  this.blurListener.remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set **condition** for costume function that u write for hardware button , for example when ( for example for *React Native Router Flux* ) `Actions.currentScene === 'Home'` do something or other conditions u want .