# how can I disable default BackHandler without overriding it in individual scene?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation-drawer, react-navigation, react-native-router-flux

So here is the routes I'm working with:

```
<Router>
                <Scene key="root" hideNavBar>
                    <Stack key="Auth" initial={!this.state.isLoggedIn}>
                        <Scene key="Login" hideNavBar component={Login} title="Login" />
                    </Stack>
                    <Stack key="Main" initial={this.state.isLoggedIn}>
                        <Scene drawer key="NavDrawer" hideNavBar contentComponent={() => <NavDrawer username={this.state.userName} />} type={ActionConst.REPLACE} panHandlers={null}>
                            <Scene key="homeTab" navBar={() => <PageHeader title='Home' />} drawerLockMode={'locked-closed'}>
                                <Scene tabs={true} tabBarComponent={ScrollableTabBar} tabBarPosition='top' lazy={true}>
                                    <Scene key="Home" hideNavBar component={Home} title={"Home"} name='Home'/>
                                </Scene>
                                <Scene key="itemDescription" hideNavBar component={itemDescription} title="Item Description" back />
                            </Scene>
                            <Scene key="helpTab" navBar={() => <PageHeader title='Help' />} title="Help" drawerLockMode={'locked-closed'}>
                                <Scene>
                                    <Scene key="Help" hideNavBar component={Help} title={"Help"} />
                                </Scene>
                            </Scene>
                            <Scene key="settingTab" navBar={() => <PageHeader title='Settings' />} title="Settings" drawerLockMode={'locked-closed'}>
                                <Scene>
                                    <Scene key="Setting" hideNavBar component={Setting} title={"Setting"} />
                                </Scene>
                            </Scene>
                            <Scene key="QRTab" navBar={() => <PageHeader title='QR Scanner' />} title="QR" drawerLockMode={'locked-closed'}>
                                <Scene>
                                    <Scene key="QRScanner" hideNavBar component={QRScanner} title={"QR Scanner"} />
                                </Scene>
                            </Scene>
                        </Scene>
                    </Stack>
                </Scene>
            </Router>
```

and this is the BackHandler from my `NavDrawer`:

```
handleBackButton() {
        if (Actions.currentScene === '_Home')
        this.onSignOut()
    else if (this.state.currentTab !== 'Home') {
        this.setState({ currentTab: 'Home' })
        Actions.homeTab();
    }
    else if (Actions.currentScene === 'Login')
    {
        BackHandler.exitApp();
    }
    else{
        Actions.pop();
    }
    return true;
}

componentDidMount() {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButton);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress');
}
```

It seems that RNRF drawer has implemented a default BackHandler for any newly stacked scenes under drawer with the default behaviour of `Actions.pop()`.

At this point all the logical scene movements are working as expected, however, due to the default BackHandler being called and just doing `Actions.pop()` to get back to Home, the tab highlight is not moved back to Home because setState({currentTab:'Home'}) was never executed.

Any Idea on how to disable to default handler or to do a workaround without adding individual BackHandler to each child scene in the drawer?

UPDATE:
turns out this problem only occurs when I'm auto logged in (i.e. skipped the `Auth` stack and straight into the `Main` stack), it seems something went wrong between the reloading and `componentWillUnmount` or `componentDidMount` not being called and BackHandlers from previous reloads collide somehow.

Because if I try this scenario:

`login --> Setting/Help/QR tab --> hardware back to Home` it doesn't cause the problem

but if I do:

`autoLogin(login using stored token) --> Setting/Help/QR tab --> hardware back to Home` the default BackHandler will be called, but if I press back once again, the desired BackHandler is called and I'm logged out, then if I try to login again, everything works perfectly!

UPDATE2:

I can confirm now that the problem lies in hot reloading, when app reloads, `componentWillUnmount` is never called, and as it is loaded back, `componentDidMount` is called again and now we have 2 BackHandlers which handles the same event (and I dont know how they are supposed to behave in this case, but that causes the handler with `Actions.pop()` to be used instead of the one I defined).

This is why when I log out (and `componentWillUnmount` called and removed the BackHandler) and log in once again (which then loads a new BackHandler on a clean slate via `componentDidMount`) everything works fine.

Now my new question is, will this cause problem if there wasn't any hot reload and the user simply closed the app and open it again (when the app is actually installed not loaded via expo like now)?

Answer (score 0):

In your BackHandler eventlistener try this. Please make sure to put this in a root component

```
let routeName = this.props.navigation.state.routeName // If you're using react navigation
let routeName = Actions.currentScene // If you're using router flux

BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', function() {

  if (routeName !== "Home") {
    this.props.navigation.goBack() // or create go back custom function 
    Actions.pop() // If your're using router flux
    return true;
  }
  return false;
});
```

Comment: still the same behaviour unfortunately :( u reckon this could have something to do with hot reloading from expo? because if we hot reload, NavDrawer's componentWillUnmount might not be called and might cause colision with previous listener? because I just noticed that this only happens if I get under the scenario where I am auto logged in after a hot reload

Comment: please check out my update on the post to get a clearer idea of the situation :) thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Why do you have 2 listener. 1 listener is enough and make sure to put it in a root component not by every screen . If you want to create logic per screen follow as my answer above

Comment: what I'm trying to say is that 2 listeners happens by accident because `componentWillUnmount` is not called when app is either closed with the square button and swipe close gesture OR hot reloaded during development.  So now I need a workaround for that case it seems. the problem doesn't lie in the way I add the listener, but the way react-native component lifecycle hook behaves (not calling `componentWillUnmount` on app close or hot reload)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41189619/react-native-componentwillunmount-not-being-called. Maybe this might help you.